# List.AddRange result from LINQ marked with AsParallel()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parallel-processing

Consider the following example.

```
result.AddRange(
    data.AsParallel()
        .Where(cs => cs is internalHistorySet)
            .Select(matchingItem => new History(source, (internalHistorySet)matchingItem)));
```

I've got two questions about the code:

1. Does the `AsParallel()` only affect the query itself? IMO It wouldn't make any sense if the items are being added parallel as `AddRange` just takes an `IEnumerable`. The way I understand the code it simply executes the query parallel, means that the query itself might be faster compared to not using AsParallel. However, performance of `AddRange` itself doesn't change because it's not affected.
2. Does the position of `AsParallel()` matter? Would it be the same if it was at the end of the query?

Greetings & Thanks

Comment: Also, I'd suggest benchmarking to determine if the `AsParallel` actually speeds it up. Sometimes (often) it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the AsParallel() only affect the query itself?

Yes.

> However, performance of AddRange itself doesn't change because it's
>   not affected.

Correct. I mean, `AddRange` **may** take longer, but that would be because the enumerable (that it is iterating over) is being served up differently by the LINQ query. The difference in perf will be because of the LINQ query, not `AddRange` itself.

> Would it be the same if it was at the end of the query?

It would be pointless to use `AsParallel` if it was at the end. `AsParallel` only impacts the stuff **after it** in the LINQ query. Nothing after it == pointless.